# Can we call a web Service/REST API from BASIC(Beginner's All-purpose Symbolic Instruction Code) programming language

Tags: rest, web-services, basic, plc

I've [nano 10 PLC](http://www.triplc.com/nano10.htm) which records some data in its memory i need that data on my web application we can program the PLC with "[Ladder + BASIC](http://www.tri-plc.com/trilogiintro.htm)" language that can easily handle sophisticated tasks with just a few lines of codes now my requirement is get PLC recorded data to my web application through Web Service or REST API call is it possible to call api if so how to proceed with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use `TCPCONNECT` to establish the connection.

`PRINT #4 "<TCPCONNECT 192.168.0.51:3000>"`

Use `STATUS(3)` to check if the connection has been established or not.

```
IF STATUS(3)
    SETLCD 1,1,"Connected"
ELSE
    SETLCD 1,1,"NOT Connected"
    GOTO 100
ENDIF
```

Then send the request

```
PRINT #4 "GET /hello.htm HTTP/1.1"
PRINT #4 ""   ' this is important
```

You have to follow the HTTP protocol format. For other methods, refer https://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#othermethods

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://www.triplc.com/Sample_Programs.htm

You will find tbasic sample code for tcp/ip. Make sure you format your request like a normal http GET or POST request. You will have to serialize your data to JSON.

Comment: can you elaborate more on this i just looked into it, can you give example. i'm new to tbasic language